# Prove, $\sqrt{n} \le (n!)^\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{n+1}{2} $

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following inequality,
$$\sqrt{n} \le (n!)^\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{n+1}{2} \ \ \ \ \forall \ n\in \mathbb{N} $$

Comment: You can use Stirling's formula.

Comment: @HenryW what is stirling's formula. Can you solve it? please

Answer (score 7):

Arithmetic geometric mean inequality for the right side.

$$ \frac{1 + 2 + \dots + n}{n} \ge (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

For the left side,

$$ \frac{1 + 1/2 + \dots + 1/n}{n} \ge \frac{1}{(n!)^{1/n}}$$

$$ 1 + 1/2 + \dots + 1/n \le \sqrt{n},\quad n \gt 4$$

The last one is easily proved using induction.

Look ma, no stirlings!

Comment: Nice application of the beloved HM-GM-AM-QM!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to the left side:

For $1\leq k \leq n$,
$$0\leq(n-k)(k-1)=nk-k^2-n+k$$
$$n\leq nk-k^2+k = k(n-k+1)$$
$$\ln n \leq \ln k + \ln (n-k+1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln n =n\cdot \ln n\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k + \ln (n-k+1)=2\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k$$
$$\frac{\ln n}{2} \leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k}{n}=\frac{\ln n!}{n}$$
$$\sqrt n \leq n!^\frac1n$$

Comment: That is a very clever method