# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{1! + 2! + 3! + \dots + n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{1! + 2! + 3! + \dots + n!}$$

I can try at least to evaluate it from bottom:

$$1 < \sqrt[n^2]{n^2} < \sqrt[n^2]{n!} < \sqrt[n^2]{1! + 2! + \dots + n!}$$

Well, it doesn't say anything. Ok, gonna try evaluation from top.

$$\sqrt[n^2]{1! + 2! + \cdots + n!} < \sqrt[n^2]{n \times n!}$$

More than that,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{1! + 2! + \cdots + n!} = 1$$

but this equation is always less than one.  So instead of writing $\sqrt[n^2]{n \times n!}$ I can try fixed coefficient $1 < a < n$. It will work for $a = 2$, $a =1.5$, but I'm not sure though about $a = (1 + \frac{1}{n})$

$$\sqrt[n^2]{1! + 2! + \cdots + n!} < \sqrt[n^2]{a \times n!}$$

Just to get broad idea how it looks I'll assume that $a = 1$ and I'll try to use Stirling's approximation

$$\sqrt[n^2]{1 \times n!} \approx \left((2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \right)^\frac{1}{n^2} = (2 \pi n)^{\frac{1}{2n^2}} \times \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$, $2n^2 > 2 \pi n$, $\frac{n}{e} < n$ (for big numbers) mean, that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(2 \pi n)^{\frac{1}{2n^2}} \times (\frac{n}{e})^{\frac{1}{n}} \approx 1$$

So I can guess, that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + n!}  = 1$$

But I sincerely doubt that what I wrote here is barely a solution. Would you mind helping me? Hope I didn't make huge mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's known that $n^{1/n}\to1$, and so will $\sqrt[n^2]{n}\to1$ even faster. However, $\sqrt[n^2]{n^2}\neq1$ so I don't know why you drop down to $n^2$. As $1!+2!+\cdots+n!>1$, $\sqrt[n^2]{...}>1$ is automatic.

From above: $$\sqrt[n^2]{n\cdot n!}=\sqrt[n^2]{n}\cdot\sqrt[n^2]{n!}\sim\sqrt[n^2]{n!}$$And: $$n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$So: $$\sqrt[n^2]{n!}\sim n^{1/n}e^{-1/n}(2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}\to1$$Using $a^{1/n}\to1$ for all $a>0$ as well.

I don't know why you are 'trying fixed coefficients $1<a<2$'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @KratosTheFarmer So do we all. You're welcome. We can even avoid the Stirling formula (which is 'high level') and use the more elementary [bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1552694/815585) $n!\le\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n$ to deduce $\sqrt[n^2]{n!}\le\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{1/n}\to1$

Comment: Even the easy bound $n! < n^n$ suffices.

Comment: @DanielSchepler True!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that :
$$1 \leq \sqrt[n^2]{1! + \cdots + n!} \leq \sqrt[n^2]{n! + \cdots + n!} = \sqrt[n^2]{n \, n!} \leq \sqrt[n^2]{n n^n} = \sqrt[n^2]{n^{n + 1}} \to 1$$
because :
$$\ln \sqrt[n^2]{n^{n + 1}} = \dfrac{1}{n^2} \ln n^{n + 1} = \dfrac{n + 1}{n} \, \dfrac{\ln n}{n} \to 1 \times 0 = 0$$